# Getting current scroll position using Scroller object

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scroll

I have an imageview that is larger than the screen size so I am using a `Scroller`object `myScroller` to handle the scrolling. However, I cannot get the correct **current scroll position**.

I have tried using the methods outlined in the developer guides for Scroller:

- `myScroller.getCurrX()` and `myScroller.getCurrY()`
- `myScroller.getStartX()` and `myScroller.getStartY()`

And then there is the `getScrollX()` and `getScrollY()` methods for the `View` class... which are the correct methods to use?

I am updating the position in the onTouchEvent under the `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        //if(mScroller.isFinished()){
        mScroller.computeScrollOffset();
        mPosX = getScrollX(); // **should this be myScroller.getCurrX()?**
        mPosY = getScrollY();
        //Log.d("OnScale", "scrollPosition: [" + mPosX + ", " + mPosY + "]");
        }
```

But this does not seem to update the scrollPosition correctly *every* time. What is the correct way to get the scroll position of my imageview? To clarify, I would like the coordinates of the **top left corner**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure out that

- `getScrollX()`
- `getScrollY()`

is the correct way to get the scroll position of the child view. I'm still not sure why/what the difference is between this an using the `Scroller.getCurrX()/getCurrY` methods, but they definitely return drastically different values sometimes.